# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen sidekiq.pid on Docker Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, sidekiq

I am trying to make it work rails dockerized project containers inside EC2 AWS and I am running without success.

the RoR project depends on sidekiq, postgres and redis, so I builded a 'production image' with docker for rails (web service), and sidekiq (sidekiq service), and currently I try to make it work with docker-compose for production

I have to say, everything in my local machine work fine. develop and 'production' images work as expected, the problem appears when compose up the 'production' images (web and sidekiq) in EC2 AWS machine.

I am getting this error:

```
production_sidekiq | No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /my_app/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:370:in `initialize'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:370:in `open'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:370:in `write_pid'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:43:in `parse'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/bin/sidekiq:11:in `<top (required)>'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<top (required)>'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
production_sidekiq | /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

In my docker-compose.yml for production on EC2 I have this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.5
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_DB: my_app_production
    env_file:
      - ~/production.env

  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.11

  web:
    container_name: prod_web
    image: prod_my_app:latest
    command: bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0' -e production
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    environment: 
      RAILS_ENV: production 
      RACK_ENV: production 
      RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: 'true' 
      RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: 'true' 
      EXECJS_RUNTIME: Disabled 
      SECRET_KEY_BASE: token 
      DEVISE_SECRET_KEY: token 
    env_file:
      - ~/production.env
    restart: always

  sidekiq:
    container_name: production_sidekiq
    image: prod_my_app_sidekiq:latest
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    environment: 
      RAILS_ENV: production 
      RACK_ENV: production 
      RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: 'true' 
      RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: 'true' 
      EXECJS_RUNTIME: Disabled 
      SECRET_KEY_BASE: token 
      DEVISE_SECRET_KEY: token 
    env_file:
      - ~/production.env
    restart: always`
```

And in config/sidekiq.yml

```
:verbose: true
:concurrency: 1
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
staging:
  :concurrency: 10
production:
  :concurrency: 20
:queues:
  - default
  - mailers
```

I am stuck, I had thought that this was a problem of volumes, since I have another file for 'local production test images' and binded volumes: - .:/my_app inside sidekiq and web services, so in production I deleted this lines as mention [Docker Compose in Production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/#modify-your-compose-file-for-production) but I get error `production_sidekiq | No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /my_app/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid`

Puma server on web service runs ok.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a pidfile so why create one?  Remove this line:

```
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
```